# How to get the Guids and mobilephone from a Party List?

Tags: crm

I'm making a windows service that triggers on the create message of a custom activity SMS. These program will send the actual sms using a third party sms service provider.

Therefore I need to get the mobilephone numbers for every contact/lead/user/account in the "To" field of the SMS activity. This is a field of type: Party List.

In addition I have another field ("new_msisdn") which I use it if "to" field be empty.(In this field user will type phone numbers directly)

I'm currently using the following code:

```
EntityCollection results =   CrmService.RetrieveMultiple(query);           
string msisdn;
string newmessage;
Entity entity;
int encode;
bool flash;
res = new Message[results.Entities.Count];
if (results != null && results.Entities.Count > 0)
{                
  try
      {
        for (int i = 0; i < results.Entities.Count; i++)
           {
             entity = results.Entities[i];
              msisdn = (string)entity["new_msisdn"];
 // I have to add an condition here to check if "to" is not empty , then get mobilephones.  
              newmessage = (string)entity["new_message"];
              encode = ((OptionSetValue)entity["new_messagetype"]).Value;
              flash = (bool)entity["new_flashsms"];
              res[i] = new Message();
              res[i].crmId = entity.Id;
              res[i].senderNumber = msisdn;
              res[i].sendDate = DateTime.Now;
              res[i].message = newmessage;
              if (encode == 1)
              res[i].encoding = 1;
              else
              res[i].encoding = 2;
              if (flash)
              res[i].flash = 2;
              else res[i].flash = 1;
            }
        }
```

I have no ideas to do this. By the way, I use CRM 2015.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use something like below.

```
if(entity.Attributes.Contains("to"))
{
 EntityCollection to=(EntityCollection)entitiy["to"];
 foreach(Entity toEntity in to.Entities)
  {
    //You will get each to field record here. 
    //Use that information to get the mobile numbers of respective users.
    Guid Id=toEntity.Id;
    //Below code mostly will return string.empty.
    //You may have to query CRM to get mobile number for respective contacts.
    string mobileNumber=toEntity.Attributes.Contains("mobilenumber")?toEntity["mobilenumber"].ToString():string.Empty;
  }
 }
```

Hope I have addressed your query. Please let us know if you have any further questions on the same.

Also its a best practice to check whether attribute is already available in the entity object or not before using a particular attribute.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But I found it is better to use entity reference which includs the name of entity and its GUID

Comment: Farhad, I thought you wanted to get Guid and MobileNumber. If you want the name Entity Object can have that attribute as well. I tried to answer on top of your approach of getting the data in an entity collection and then use that data further. Entity Reference is also another option for getting the guid. But for mobile phone number you may have to again hit the database using this guid and logical name. Since you already have a collection of entitie why cant you reuse that. That will avoid unnecessary DB hits right.

Comment: Thank you so much Renjith. your answer show me the way. By the way you are right, both solutions are correct but yours will cause less hit.